# Using of Operator Overloading form

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I wonder in c++ about the  operator  overloading forms of the below like:

```
ClassName & operator+(ClassName &other)
ClassName operator+(ClassName &other)
Classname operator+(const ClassName &other)
Classname operator+(const Classname other)
Classname operator+(Classname other)
```

What are the difference of usage ??

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: so, What is the specific form of operator overloading ? i always see other people write different form from each other !!

Comment: It depends on what you do. In this case, 1, 2 and 4 don't look right. Try to understand the semantics of the addition operator. What do you expect to happen and *not* to happen when you say `a + b`?

Comment: Actually, none of them look right, if they are member functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one returns a reference, and takes a reference - this means that you can theoretically change both arguments, and you return a reference, which can be changed too. This is usually not what you want to do( 2 + 3 doesn't return 5 that can be reassigned to 17).

Second one is the same, but no reference returned.

Third has const reference - a reference which can't be modified. This is usually what you want to do, since you get element fast(you get *the* element), but you can't change it(incidentally or not).

Fourth one is like a third, but you copy an argument, and make it const for some reason. This makes little sense.

And the last one just takes a copy.

There isn't much difference between some of them - some of them make little sense if you think about what `operator+` has to do; the area where they differ is mostly how you get the argument - and most of the time, you want to get it fast, so `const ClassName& other` is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference: none of the quoted operators is the one normally
actually overloaded! The one which is normally overloaded is more like
this (assuming it is in the same namespace as `ClassName`):

```
ClassName operator+ (ClassName const& op1, ClassName const& op2) {
    ClassName rc(op1);
    rc += op2;
    return rc;
}
```

There are some variations how this operator can be implemented. In
particular the first argument may be passed by value to avoid the copy
in the implementation: in some cases the copy could be elided. This particular implementation using a named variable and returning it by name is intended to enable copy elision (as @juanchopanza pointed out, `return ClassName(op1) += op2;` isn't allowed to elide the copy for the return value).

With respect to your actual question, it is important to distinguish
between references and values:

- When a value like `ClassName` is used, the object being passed to a
  function or returned from a function is a copy. When the class
  in question is trivial, that is just OK but if the class is more
  complicated and allocates memory for its members there may be some
  cost in creating actual copies. On the other hand, semantically it is
  often necessary to use a copy. For example, the result of an addition
  is normally a different object and, thus, needs to be a copy.

  To take the edge out of the some of the costs, the compiler tries
  hard to avoid copies when it can. For example, when returning a
  local variable the copy is in many cases elided or the object is,
  at least, moved (assuming C++11 or later is used and the class has
  a move constructor).
- When a reference like `ClassName&` or `ClassName const&` is used, 
  the entity is actually just a name for an object. No copy is made
  but an object needs to exist somewhere. The presence of `const` vs.
  the absence of `const` just indicates whether all methods or only
  `const` methods can be called or whether a reference can be passed
  where another reference is needed: a non-`const` reference can
  be converted to a `const` reference but not vice verse.

  For the purpose of parameters, the key difference between `const`
  reference and non-`const` reference is that temporary objects
  cannot bind to non-`const` reference while they *can* bind to
  `const` references.

With that sorted, here is a run-through of the different declarations of
the `operator+()`:

- `ClassName & operator+(ClassName &other)`

  This declaration takes a non-`const` reference as argument and returns
  a non-`const` reference. For the argument this means that it can't
  be a temporary but rather needs to have a name. For the return that
  means that the returned object needs to be kept alive. Normally the
  addition creates a new object and trying to keep an object alive
  is bound to not work. If `ClassName` is really expensive to copy
  you might not want to provide an `operator+()` but rather just
  an `operatr+=()` which semantically produces the same result as
  `operator+()` but does so in-place.
- `ClassName operator+(ClassName &other)`

  This declaration has the primary constraint that the argument is
  a non-`const` reference, i.e., the argument cannot be a temporary
  object but has to be an lvalue, i.e., something which is somehow
  named. However, the arguemnt won't be copied.
- `ClassName operator+(const ClassName &other)`

  This declaration works with temporaries and is one of the two likely
  candidates of how a member `operator+()` would look like. The argument
  still isn't copied but because it is [logically] immutable temporary
  objects can be used as arguments.
- `ClassName operator+(const ClassName other)`

  This will copy the argument. For the purpose of the declaration
  the `const` will be meaningless and it can actually differ between
  different declarations of the same function. When the definition
  uses this declaration it means that the argument is copied, i.e., the
  `operator+()` has a local version but it can't actually change this
  copy. Most likely it will need to create another copy to produce a
  result. Correspondingly, I think defining a function with a `const`
  value argument is utterly pointless: if you want a constant, use
  `const ClassName&` or `ClassName const&` (these are identical; I do
  prefer the latter notation as it results in consistent placement).
- `ClassName operator+(ClassName other)`

  Like the previous declaration this one copies the argument but the
  argument is mutable. Assuming the oepration is commutative, you can
  readily mutate `other` to produce the return value. Note, however,
  that copying `other` won't be elided (the compiler is not allowed
  to elide copying function parameters) but it can be moved. Assuming
  `ClassName` is either cheap to copy or `other` is used as the basis
  for the result, this is the other likely candidate how the operator
  is defined.

Comment: Doesn't `return ClassName(op1) += op2;` inhibit RVO? I am not sure if it does formally, but I have recollections of implementations struggling to elide a copy.

Comment: @juanchopanza: hm. `operator+=()` would return a reference to the temporary. This one can't be elided, either. Interesting point: that implies that this short notation is actually ill-advised! I shall adjust the implementation accordingly.